# Spark map function to perform column updates

Tags: apache-spark

Scala 2.11 here. I have the following `input` DB table:

```
[input]
===
id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
rank INT NOT NULL
```

I read some `input` records into a Spark `DataFrame` like so:

```
val inputDf = sqlContext().read
    .format("blah whatever")
    .option("url", "jdbc://blah://whatever")
    .option("query", "SELECT * FROM input WHERE id < 500")
    .load()
```

So far so good. I now want to loop through each row in `inputDf` and apply a transformation to the `rank` field:

```
rank = rank * 50
```

Hence if the following 3 `input` records are read in from the DB:

```
id | name | rank
================
1  | Fizz | 3
2  | Buzz | 14
3  | Foo  | 294
```

Then the resultant `DataFrame` needs to look like:

```
id | name | rank
================
1  | Fizz | 150
2  | Buzz | 700
3  | Foo  | 14700
```

I *believe* I can use a `map` function something like:

```
inputDf.map(input =>
  // I believe this gets me the value of the 3rd column (rank):
  input.getInt(3).intValue()

  // Now how to update/set rank as 'rank *= 50' ?
  ???
).collect()
```

But I'm having trouble seeing the "forest through the trees". **Any ideas?** The result should be the `inputDf` whose `rank` column/field has been updated/transformed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `withColumn`:

```
inputDf.withColumn("rank",  inputDf("rank") * 50)
```

or `select`:

```
inputDf.withColumn($"*",  ($"rank" * 50).alias("rank"))
```

Comment: Thanks @user9772786 (+1), so when does one use `withColumn` vs `map` or `foreach`?